# How to get cypress to block datadog requests

Tags: events, cypress, datadog, cypress-intercept

We recently installed datadogRUM in our application and now so many DD events kick off in my cypress test that they cause a timeout and failure

I have tried cy.intercept in multiple ways:

```js
 cy.intercept('POST', 'https://rum.browser-intake-datadoghq.com/*', {
       statusCode: 202,
       body: {
       },
     }).as('datadogRUM');

     cy.intercept('POST',  'https://rum-http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/*',  {});

     cy.intercept(/\.*datadog.*$/, (req) => {
       console.log('DATADOG INTERCEPTED');
       req.reply("console.log('datadog intercept');");
     });

    cy.intercept({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/\.*datadog.*$/'
    }, req => {
      req.destroy();
    });

    cy.intercept('POST',  'https://rum-http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/*',  { forceNetworkError: true });
```

just to start. I feel like I've tried every possible variation. I also created a cypress.json file in my /cypress folder

```js
{
"blockHosts": "*datadoghq.com/*"
}
```

I get hundreds of calls back in my network tab to `https://rum.browser-intake-datadoghq.com/api/v2/rum` with the preview of `console.log('datadog intercept')` as I've intercepted them. They all display the solid blue line as if they are being intercepted and blocked. When I set the intercept to an alias I see the alias in my cypress runner window. But there are no `503`s or `404`s anywhere. The page still fills up with events, cypress gets overloaded, and my test times out.

I even tried copying the `data-dog-rum.ts` from the src/utils folder to cypress/utils and either commenting out everything or setting the `sampleRate` to `0`, no dice.

EDIT: I am able to get the test passing by adding

```
 
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false;
});
```

to my `support/index.js` but now whether I add a cy.intercept in my test makes absolutely no difference. The page still fills up with datadog requests regardless, and whether they come back as 200/pending/cancelled, they still delay a single it block in a spec to where it takes 60 seconds to run instead of approx 10 seconds

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to perform the stub inside the routeHandler

```js
cy.intercept('*', (req) => {  // look at everything
  if (req.url.includes('datadoghq')) {      // add more conditions if needed
    req.reply({})                           // prevent request reaching the server
  }
})
```

`blockhosts` should work with

> Pass only the host

```js
{
  "blockHosts": "*datadoghq.com"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, still getting the same result :(

Comment: At least now you have a chance to examine the routes in javascript - it's easy to `console.log(req.url)` and see what is being captured.

Comment: If you are not seeing ***anything*** inside the route handler, then you're setting up the intercept too late in the test.

Comment: So the url printed out: https://rum.browser-intake-datadoghq.com/api/v2/rum?ddsource=browser&ddtags=sdk_version%etc.... truncating for proprietary information. I put the intercept in the beforeEach hook.I still see a little black box with white text that says something like 'Waiting for datadog...' and a lot of '[Violation] 'message' handler took <N>ms' in my console

Comment: I also see about 13 POSTS with a 200 response for datadog before seeing the remaining POSTS in status of pending or cancelled

Comment: So, I'm getting the impression that `Waiting for datadog` means you are performing a `cy.wait()` on the intercept alias. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Nope, definitely not putting a cy.wait() anywhere, it's an anti-pattern I try to avoid at all costs. I think that's probably coming from the source code?

Comment: Looks like you've confused `cy.wait()` with a fixed time to `cy.wait()` for an alias. Why would you use `.as('datadogRUM')` shown above if you are not going to wait for it?

Comment: Ah! Gotcha. Those are all separate ways I've tried to use cy.intercept. Let me know if one of them looks like could work if I tweaked it somehow. Cy.intercept doesn't seem that complicated, not sure why none of them work

Comment: So this is still a constant issue for me. Waiting does nothing and my cypress console still fills up with requests. Ex)   cy.intercept({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/\.*datadog.*$/'
    }).as('datadog');
    cy.wait('@datadog');

Comment: @TesterDick can you clarify which files you are supposed to add this code to, and can do you have to do both things or only one?